How to calculate the torque on a slowly rotating sphere in a newtonian fluid?
A sphere with radius $a$ is submerged in a highly viscous incompressible fluid. The sphere rotates about its own diameter with a small constant angular velocity $\omega$, causing the fluid to move. Assuming external forces are negligible and the pressure remains constant during the motion, find the total viscous torque acting on the sphere.
Below is my idea.
In spherical coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$ :
Since the sphere rotates around its diameter, the problem is axisymmetric, and the velocity field only has a $\phi$-component, $v_\phi$. The velocity $v_\phi$ depends only on $r$ and $\theta$.
Boundary Conditions:

On the sphere surface $(r=a)$ :

$$
v_\phi=\omega a \sin \theta
$$

At infinity $(r \rightarrow \infty)$ :

$$
v_\phi=0
$$
The Navier-Stokes (NS) equations in spherical coordinates are:

Radial Component $r$-direction:

$$
\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial t}+v_r \frac{\partial v_r}{\partial r}+\frac{v_\theta}{r} \frac{\partial v_r}{\partial \theta}+\frac{v_\phi}{r \sin \theta} \frac{\partial v_r}{\partial \phi}-\frac{v_\theta^2+v_\phi^2}{r}=-\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial p}{\partial r}+\nu\left[\nabla^2 v_r-\frac{2}{r^2} v_r\right]+f_r
$$

Polar Component $\theta$-direction:

$$
\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial t}+v_r \frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial r}+\frac{v_\theta}{r} \frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial \theta}+\frac{v_\phi}{r \sin \theta} \frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial \phi}+\frac{v_r v_\theta}{r}-\frac{v_\phi^2 \cot \theta}{r}=-\frac{1}{\rho r} \frac{\partial p}{\partial \theta}+\nu\left[\nabla^2 v_\theta-\frac{v_\theta}{r^2 \sin ^2 \theta}\right]+f_\theta
$$

Azimuthal Component $\phi$-direction:

$$
\frac{\partial v_\phi}{\partial t}+v_r \frac{\partial v_\phi}{\partial r}+\frac{v_\theta}{r} \frac{\partial v_\phi}{\partial \theta}+\frac{v_\phi}{r \sin \theta} \frac{\partial v_\phi}{\partial \phi}+\frac{v_r v_\phi}{r}+\frac{v_\theta v_\phi \cot \theta}{r}=-\frac{1}{\rho r \sin \theta} \frac{\partial p}{\partial \phi}+\nu\left[\nabla^2 v_\phi-\frac{v_\phi}{r^2 \sin ^2 \theta}\right]+f_\phi
$$
Since the velocity field only has a $\phi$-component $\left(v_\phi\right)$, and the problem is steady and axisymmetric $(\partial / \partial t=0, \partial / \partial \phi=0)$, most terms vanish. We are left with:
$$
\nabla^2 v_\phi-\frac{v_\phi}{r^2 \sin ^2 \theta}=0
$$
Solution:
Assume that $v_\phi$ has the form:
$$
v_\phi=f(r) \sin \theta
$$
Substitute this form into the  equation:
$$
\sin \theta\left[\frac{d^2 f}{d r^2}+\frac{2}{r} \frac{d f}{d r}-\frac{2 f}{r^2}\right]=0
$$
The term in brackets must be zero:
$$
\frac{d^2 f}{d r^2}+\frac{2}{r} \frac{d f}{d r}-\frac{2 f}{r^2}=0
$$
Solve this equation by letting $f(r)=\frac{A}{r^2}$, where $A$ is a constant. Substitute $f(r)$ into the equation to verify that it satisfies the equation.
Apply Boundary Conditions:

From the first boundary condition $(r=a)$ :

$$
\frac{A}{a^2}=\omega a \Longrightarrow A=\omega a^3
$$

The second boundary condition $(r \rightarrow \infty)$ is automatically satisfied because $v_\phi \rightarrow 0$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$.

Final Solution:
The velocity field is:
$$
v_\phi=\omega a^3 \sin \theta \cdot \frac{1}{r^2}.
$$
But I don't know how to further calculate the stress. Also, the formula for torque is given as:
$$
\boldsymbol{M}=\int_S \boldsymbol{r} \times(\boldsymbol{\tau} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}) d S
$$
$\tau$ is the stress tensor on the surface, and $n$ is the unit outward normal vector of the surface. However, I am not sure how to use it. Could someone provide some guidance or hints? Thank you very much!
